# Using an array im mysql with LIKE CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using the following code to get rows from the database

```
$get_brand_filter_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand WHERE ('$arrBrands[0]'     LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[1]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[2]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[3]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[4]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[5]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[6]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[7]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
OR '$arrBrands[8]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')
)", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
```

As you can see I'm having to manually list elements of the array held in $arrBrands. Problem is that the array can have a8s many as 500 entries.

How do I expode? the array so I don't have to keep writing it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you have a fixed number of elements in the array, you can just do a loop replacing the index.

Comment: What is the semantics of your `brand.brand_name` field?  Perhaps it needs normalisation, in which case you might simply be able to search `WHERE brand_name IN ('val1', 'val2', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this...

```
$array = array('puma', 'adidas', 'nike', 'reebok');
$condition = implode("' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')) OR ('", $array);
$query = "SELECT * FROM brand WHERE (('$condition' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')));";

// SELECT * FROM brand WHERE (('puma' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')) OR ('adidas' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')) OR ('nike' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')) OR ('reebok' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')))
```

**[Codepad](http://codepad.org/DyRg95xU)**

Comment: i believe you need single quotes before implode and after like `"'" . implode() . "'";`. or maybe not.

Comment: do you need all those `()`'s ? and i think you have 1 too many

Comment: I went for this a it's the shortest. Works like a charm, no need for the additional single quotes. Many, many thanks.

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal you have 5 `(` and 9 `)` how does that work with missing parenthesizes

Comment: @Class.. You need a coffee!!

Comment: @AshwiniAgarwal woops my bad just too many parenthesizes and you don't really need them if they are all OR's. Plus I don't drink coffee.

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code.

```
$count = count($arrBrands);
$seperator = ''
foreach($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
    $sql_part = $seperator."'$arrBrands[".$i."]' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')";
    $seperator  = ' OR '
}
$get_brand_filter_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand WHERE $sql_part)", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$str    = "";
$apn    = ' OR ';
foreach( $arrBrands as $key => $each ){
    $str    .= "('{$each}' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%')".$apn;
}
$str    = substr( $str, 0, strlen( $str )-3 );
$get_brand_filter_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brand WHERE {$str}", $db2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better use a different approach (mysql_query is an 'old way': `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated)), but you can cycle on the array (code not tested):

```
$q ="SELECT * FROM brand ";
reset($arrBrands);
$lOr=false;
while(list($key,$brand)=each($arrBrands)) {
    $q.=($lOr?" OR ":" WHERE ")."'$brand' LIKE CONCAT(brand_name, '%') ";
    $lOr=true;
}
$get_brand_filter_result = mysql_query($q, $db2) or die(mysql_error());
```